# Python object method is seeing self argument as missing

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a text based game to teach myself python. I try to access the attribute of an object stored in the player object. The object is a copy of the map data object representing their position on the map.

When i run the function as it is, when the look method of the player object is called, the method sees the self argument as a missing argument.  If I try to access the room data stored in the player object and pass it in (which doesn't seem right anyway as it should already be in the object instance), it then says the attribute doesn't exist.  After the program crashes, in the interpreter I can access the attribute without error.  I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
class quadPoint:

    def __init__(self, data):

    self.pointData = {'description' : '', 'west': '','east': '',
            'north': '','south': ''}
    self.exits = []
    self.inventory = []

    self.pointData['description'] = data[0]
    self.pointData['west'] = data[1]
    self.pointData['east'] = data[2]
    self.pointData['north'] = data[3]
    self.pointData['south'] = data[4]

    def addItem(self, item):
    self.inventory.append(item)

    def addExit(self, ext):
    self.exits.append(ext)

rooms = [
    ['A discription1','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription2','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription3','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription4','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription5','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription6','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription7','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription8','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription'],
    ['A discription9','A discription','A discription','A discription','A discription']
    ]

roomExits = {
    '00':[ [0,1],[1,0] ], # 0,0
    '01':[ [0,0],[0,2],[1,1] ],  # 0,1
    '02':[ [0,1],[1,2] ], # 0,2
    '10':[ [0,0],[1,1],[2,0] ], # 1,0
    '11':[ [1,0],[1,2],[0,1],[2,1] ], # 1,1
    '12':[ [1,1],[2,2] ], # 1,2
    '20':[ [1,0],[2,1] ], # 2,0
    '21':[ [2,0],[1,1],[2,2] ], # 2,1
    '22':[ [2,1],[1,2] ], # 2,2
    }

class World :

    def __init__(self, data, exits):
    self.worldData = [ [],[],[] ]
    self.generate(data, exits)

    def getRoom(self,x,y):
    return self.worldData[x][y]


    def generate(self, data, exits):
    ph = 0
    for array in self.worldData:
       for i in range(0,3):
           array.append('')

    for x in range(0,3):
        for i in range(0,3):
            self.worldData[x][i] = quadPoint(data[ph])
            ph += 1

    for quards in exits:
        for e in exits[quards]:
            self.worldData[int(quards[0])][int(quards[1])].addExit(self.worldData[e[0]][e[1]])


class Player :


    def __init__(self, room):

    self.statData = {}


    self.equipment = { 'head' : '', 'neck' : '', 'leftEar' : '',
              'rightEar' : '', 'leftShoulder' : '',
              'rightShoulder' : '', 'chest' : '',
              'leftUpperArm' : '', 'rightUpperArm' : '',
              'leftLowerArm' : '', 'rightLowerArm' : '',
              'leftFinger0' : '','leftFinger1' : '',
              'leftFinger2' : '','leftFinger3' : '',
              'leftFinger4' : '','rightFinger0' : '',
              'rightFinger1' : '','rightFinger2' : '',
              'rightFinger3' : '','rightFinger4' : '',
              'leftWrist' : '','rightWrist' : '',
              'upperBack' : '','lowerBack' : '','back' : '','Waist' : '',
              'leftUpperLeg' : '','rightUpperLeg' : '',
              'leftLowerLeg' : '','rightLowerLeg' : '',
              'leftAnkle' : '','rightAnkle' : '',
              'leftFoot' : '','rightFoot' : ''}

    print("What would you like your name to be?")
    print()
    self.name = input(">>> ")
    print('''What would you like your name to be
    Wizard
    Fighter
    Thief
    ''')
    self.plrClass = input(">>> ")
    self.currentRoom = room


    def look(self, where):
        return self.currentRoom.pointData[where]




class Game :

    def __init__(self):
    self.world = World(rooms, roomExits)
    self.player = Player(self.world.getRoom(0,0))

    def start(self):
    self.running = True
    while self.running is True:
        print(player.look( 'description'))
        print()
        print("What do you want to do?")
        print()
        usrInput = input(">>> ")

        if userInput == 'quit': self.running = False


game = Game()

game.start()
```

the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/groundscore/pytextrpg.py", line 128, in <module>
    game.start()
  File "/home/groundscore/pytextrpg.py", line 117, in start
    print(player.look( 'description'))
TypeError: look() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Something that I don't think is responsible for your current problems, but will probably bite you later is your widespread use of class variables. If you declare a variable like `pointData` at the top level of a class, the object will only be created once and shared by all instances of the class. When you later mutate it in place, you'll see the changes in every instance, not only the one doing the mutation. That will be very confusing. Instead, you probably want to create your variables as attributes of `self` in the `__init__` method, as you're doing for some, but not all of your data.

Answer (score 4):

aruisdante beat me to the immediate answer.  A deeper problem, and the reason for the particular error message is using the same lowercase word for both class and instance thereof.  If the player class were Player, then `print(player...)` would have failed with `NameError: name 'player' is not defined` and you would not have seen the confusing message that resulted from `player.look` being resolved as the `look` attribute of the player class.

Also, `game = game()` is more confusing than `game = Game()`, and prevents further access to the game class by its name.

Comment: Ah you're right, I didn't dig into the wall of code very deeply. It bothered me that as written the code even compiled, but silly me assumed it must have been OP typographical error (which there has been a lot of lately) rather than looking for what could cause that symptom.

Comment: i see what you mean but correcting it does not change the error, what ever the error is from, you found a flaw in my logic that would have came back to bite me

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure if you're properly describing your error (it would be helpful if you included the exact error text, not your description of it), but certainly here:

```
print(player.look( 'description'))
```

Should instead be:

```
print(self.player.look( 'description'))
```

As `player` is an attribute of the `game` class. Also, you should *not* use `is` for string comparisons, you should use `==`.